# Spell-check blacklisting word sequences

Tags: spell-checking

I am a programmer and use Vim primarily for that, but I have found that enabling Vim's spell check is a somewhat useful feature to have just to help slightly incentivize cleaning up the parts of files that are written in English.

Now what I thought about just now is I think it would be cool if I could have this system mark certain arbitrary word sequences like "the the" as an error for me. Is this possible?

I know that I can use `zw` to mark a word as bad, but I want to do it for a sequence of words that I want to also treat as wrong (but which may be made up of words that are fine).

(use `:set spell` to enable spell check in Vim)

Comment: Wait a second... So I wrote this question before testing it, and it looks like the spell check ALREADY marks "the the" as a "spelling" error. Mind blown. Question still remains, though. How to add to this list?

Comment: `:help spell-BAD`

Answer (score 9):

Alright, so I looked it up this way since I had Vim's source code lying around:

```
$ cd ~/Documents/vim
$ ack 'the the'

...

runtime/doc/spell.txt
399:It can also be used to recognize "the the" and highlight it.
1206:"the the" in the .dic file:
1208:   the the/! ~
1463:   REP the_the the ~

...
```

OK so [Vim's documentation](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/spell.txt.html#spellfile-cleanup) itself appears to explain the situation (though not to my own satisfaction):

> WORD COMBINATIONS
>
> It is possible to spell-check words that include a space.  This is
>   used to recognize words that are invalid when used by themselves, e.g.
>   for "et al.". It can also be used to recognize "the the" and highlight
>   it.

There's a bunch more documentation that goes in depth into how and what the spell system is capable of. It's mostly sort of boring.

I also discovered the best way to easily add a word sequence to the "bad spelling" list. **Just use** `zw` **in visual mode** after selecting the sequence you want to mark as bad (the mnemonic is `w` for "wrong"). It works great. What it does automatically is add the word sequence to the spellfile such as `~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add` in a line ending with `/!` which means it's a "bad word".

Comment: The bolding makes the `zw` look like capitals.

Comment: @muru edited...